# Temporarily turning on and off Bluetooth in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, permissions, bump

I am trying to create a bump feature on my iOS app. It would be quite simple to do this using the Bluetooth in the phone but I believe that would prompt me to ask for permission to turn on bluetooth each time and also bluetooth would not disable itself after the bump is complete. Is there any way I can have the user agree initially to allow bluetooth to be turned on and off temporarily just during the bump when the app is first opened by the user. Thanks for any help or ideas.

I dont mind swift or ObjC

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not allow enabling or disabling system stuff by programming.

Comment: It would be better if you linked to an article where it says this is true.

Comment: Do you have any ideas for a solution?